# Photo Manipulation and texture... like instagram

Tags: photoshop-effects

Does anyone have any recommendations, links, or tutorials on how to create a similar effect to this using a normal photo?

[image]

More: http://www.behance.net/gallery/Nike-60-Surfcali/1242523

My goal is to create a subdued, dream like photo with gritty, tactile texture.

Comment: Open the 'normal photo' in instagram and apply the filters.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at the results of DeviantArt's query “[instagram tutorial](http://browse.deviantart.com/?qh=&section=&global=1&q=instagram%20tutorial)”. There should be some action pack IIRC. You could also repeat this query elsewhere (e.g. Google).

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:
[tutorial](http://abduzeedo.com/quick-tips-instagram-your-images-using-photoshop)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do the step-by-step tutorial (in case you need to repeat this process a lot of times, for example), you could download one of the many already-made photoshop actions to imitate instagram effects.

Take a look here for a list of all effects: http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/articles/10-photoshop-actions-to-create-instagram-style-effects

That particular one you mentioned could be similar to "Pale and bright": http://chic-chick.deviantart.com/art/Bright-and-pale-91781369

Original:

[image]

After the action:

[image]